# Jinja2 version 2.8 on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2

Currently Jinja version 2.6 is the only officially supported version available on app engine.  Is there a reliable way to load version 2.8 instead of their supported / built-in version 2.6?

Here is an excerpt from my existing includes / libraries code in the startup.yaml file which loads Jinja2.6 fine:

```
includes:
- lib/terminal/
- lib/recovery/

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

In our startup.py file we have a bunch of imports and then this line:

```
import webapp2 from webapp2_extras
import sessions, jinja2
```

I was thinking I should just be able to throw the 2.8 code into my lib folder and add it as an include or import it slightly differently but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there maybe another version of webapp2 I should be using or another way to do this include?

Comment: That import line appears incorrect (2 lines joined?). Can you please re-check? Also - why do you have such imports? - to use the builtin jinja2 you just need an `import jinja2` statement...

Comment: moved my import to match our code - I think we've resolved this, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete that entry from your `app.yaml`'s libraries section and then vendor the latest jinja2 library that you want to use since it's a pure python package:

```
pip install Jinja2==2.8 -t lib
```

Then add to app engine in your `appengine_config.py`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
```

More on vendoring at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring